# Include HTML files in R Markdown file?

Tags: html, r, markdown, r-markdown

## Quick Summary

How do I place HTML files ***in place*** within an R Markdown file?

## Details

I have created some nice animated choropleth maps via [choroplethr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/choroplethr/vignettes/g-animated-choropleths.html).

As the link demonstrates, the animated choropleths function via creating a set of PNG images, which are then rolled into an HTML file that cycles through the images, to show the animation.  Works great, looks great.

But now I want to embed / incorporate these pages within the .Rmd file, so that I have a holistic report including these animated choropleths, along with other work.

It seems to me there should be an easy way to do an equivalent to

Links:

```
[please click here](http://this.is.where.you.will.go.html)
```

or

Images:

```
![cute cat image](http://because.that.is.what.we.need...another.cat.image.html)
```

The images path is precisely what I want:  a reference that is "blown up" to put the information in place, instead of just as a link.  How can I do this with a full HTML file instead of just an image?  Is there any way?

## Explanation via Example

Let's say my choropleth HTML file lives in my local path at `'./animations/demographics.html'`, and I have an R Markdown file like:

```
---
title: 'Looking at the demographics issue'
author: "Mike"
date: "April 9th, 2016"
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: no
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
fontsize: 12pt
---

# Introduction

Here is some interesting stuff that I want to talk about.  But first, let's review those earlier demographic maps we'd seen.

!![demographics map]('./animations/demographics.html')
```

where I have assumed / pretended that `!!` is the antecedent that will do precisely what I want:  allow me to embed that HTML file in-line with the rest of the report.

## Updates

Two updates.  Most recently, I still could not get things to work, so I pushed it all up to a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/lazarillo/persuasive_analytical_report/tree/master), in case anyone is willing to help me sort out the problem.  Further details can be found at that repo's Readme file.

It seems that being able to embed HTML into an R Markdown file would be incredibly useful, so I keep trying to sort it out.

---

(Older comments)

As per some of the helpful suggestions, I tried and failed the following in the R Markdown file:

Shiny method:

````
```{r showChoro1}
shiny::includeHTML("./animations/demographics.html")
```
````

(I also added `runtime:Shiny` up in the YAML portion.)

`htmltools` method:

````
```{r showChoro1}
htmltools::includeHTML("./animations/demographics.html")
```
````

(In this case, I made no changes to the YAML.)

In the former case (`Shiny`), it did not work at all.  In fact, including the HTML seemed to muck up the functionality of the document altogether, such that the runtime seemed perpetually not-fully-functional.  (In short, while it appeared to load everything, the "loading" spindel never went away.)

In the latter case, nothing else got messed up, but it was a broken image.  Strangely, there was a "choropleth player" ribbon at the top of the document which would work, it's just that none of the images would pop up.

---

For my own sanity, I also provided simple links, which worked fine.

```
[This link](./animations/demographics.html) worked without a problem, except that it is not embedded, as I would prefer.
```

So it is clearly a challenge with the embedding.

Comment: @chinsoon12 Yeah, I tried that but it didn't work.  It's possible that I'd tried it incorrectly, but I did something similar to here (  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/  ) with no success.

Comment: Do it in a code chunk. `shiny::includeHTML` can do what you need.

Comment: @MikeWilliamson Did you ever figure this out, Mike? I have a similar problem.

Comment: @RobertMc No, sorry.  I never did.  :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a hack (probably inelegant)...idea is to directly insert HTML programmatically in Rmd and then render Rmd.

temp.Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Introduction"
author: "chinsoon12"
date: "April 10, 2016"
output: html_document
---

<<insertHTML:[test.html]

etc, etc, etc

```{r, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::includeHTML("test.html")
```

etc, etc, etc
````

test.html file:

```
<html>

    <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <p>This is an R HTML document. When you click the <b>Knit HTML</b> button a web page will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:</p>

        <p>test test</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

verbose code to replace Rmd code with HTML code and then render (can probably be shortened by a lot)

```
library(stringi)
subHtmlRender <- function(mdfile, htmlfile) {
    #replace <<insertHTML:htmlfile with actual html code
    #but without beginning white space
    lines <- readLines(mdfile)
    toSubcode <- paste0("<<insertHTML:[",htmlfile,"]")
    location <- which(stri_detect_fixed(lines, toSubcode) )
    htmllines <- stri_trim(readLines(htmlfile))

    #render html doc
    newRmdfile <- tempfile("temp", getwd(), ".Rmd")
    newlines <- c(lines[1:(location-1)],
                  htmllines,
                  lines[min(location+1, length(lines)):length(lines)])  #be careful when insertHTML being last line in .Rmd file
    write(newlines, newRmdfile)
    rmarkdown::render(newRmdfile, "html_document")
    shell(gsub(".Rmd",".html",basename(newRmdfile),fixed=T))
} #end subHtmlRender

subHtmlRender("temp.Rmd", "test.html")
```

---

EDIT: htmltools::includeHTML also works with the sample files that I provided. Is it because your particular html does not like UTF8-encoding?

---

EDIT: taking @MikeWilliamson comments into feedback

I tried the following

1. copied and pasted [animated_choropleth.html](https://github.com/lazarillo/persuasive_analytical_report/blob/master/SPM/animated_choropleth.html) into a blank .Rmd
2. remove references to cloudfare.com as I had access issues while
   rendering (see below)
3. knit HTML
4. put back those cloudfare weblinks
5. put the graphs in the same folder as the rendered html
6. open the HTML

I appear to get back the html but am not sure if the result is what you expect

Are you also facing the same issue in pt 2? You might want to post the error message and ask for fixes :). This was my error message

```
pandoc.exe: Failed to retrieve http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
FailedConnectionException2 "cdnjs.cloudflare.com" 80 False getAddrInfo: does not exist (error 11001)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 61
```

Comment: Hi @chinsoon12 , this definitely seems like it **should** work, but I still did not have any luck.  The code is actually not secret in any way, so I pushed it all to a GitHub repository.  It'd be awesome if you could check the link to the repository that I'd made above.  Otherwise, thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: Hi @chinsoon12 , thanks for the follow-up!  I know that error, it's from trouble with bootstrap, a means of making more flexible HTML "shapes" (allowing for larger or smaller screens).  I see you're right that I simply need to adjust the generated choroplethr HTML file itself.  I didn't think of that being the issue.  Once I figure it out well, I'll follow up with the choroplethr library folks.  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Would be helpful to everyone to describe the error and fix in a edit :)

Comment: Have you try to include HTML file in a <iframe> element?

Comment: @romles I have not tried it before. Are you facing difficulties? You can ask a question if you are facing 1.

Comment: `<<insertHTML:[test.html]` do not support mathjax but `htmltools::includeHTML("test.html")` support it, but how to adjust the size?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the ***includes:*** option in your YAML header?

https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#includes

But maybe you'll have the same problem I have: I'd like to include the HTML file in a specific section in my RMarkdown document, not in the header or before/after body.

Comment: Thanks @thbtmntgn !  That's a decent partial solution, but as you said, I wanted the HTML **embedded/integrated** into the document, not just either before or after the body.  So it doesn't (fully) work for my case.

Answer (score -4):

can try put this line in the Rmarkdown and then knit. 
(YAML header "output: html_document"; if "runtime: shiny" somehow it does not work)

Comment: Sorry, I think you're misunderstanding what I am wanting to do.  I am *not asking how to render HTML or Shiny*.  I am asking how to **place entire HTML files/pages** within the R markdown document.  I could cut & paste the HTML syntax in the file, but that is not very elegant, *and* the HTML file itself is a pre-generated, overly large garble, much like how generated HTML from R Markdown looks.