# Include HTML file into RMarkdown document to generate HTML document

Tags: html, r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

I've been developing a ***RMarkdown*** document to generate HTML reports with ***knitr*** package.

I succeed to include a HTML file containing with the ***includes:*** option in the YAML header.

The problem is that I can only choose between 3 options (https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/html_document_format.html#includes):

- ***in_header:***
- ***before_body:***
- or ***after_body:***

I'd like to include this HTML file where I want in my RMarkdown document, like in a specific section for example.

Do you know how I can do that?

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524238/include-html-files-in-r-markdown-file) but answers did not help me.

Comment: you can generate HTML for the RMarkdown and then add your HTML snippet wherever you like.

Comment: Question about the `html` file that you want to be included: is an `html` *fragment* or an `html` *standalone* file?

Comment: It's an html standalone file

Answer (score 14):

Why not using `htmltools` package? As in this similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51884897/2824732)

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::includeHTML("my_text.html")
```
````

Comment: This is great for combination with `htmltoools::includeMarkdown()`

Answer (score 10):

If you want to include a *standalone* `HTML` file, it is a **very bad practice** to include it with **in_header**, **before_body** or **after_body** or with `cat(readLines(...))`.

#### Why is it a bad practice?

A *standalone* `HTML` file is a simple text file with tags. A minimal `HTML` file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
  </body>
</html>
```

To be valid, an `HTML` file must comply with many constraints. For instance, there can be only one `<body>` element. Therefore, if you include a *standalone* `HTML` document in another `HTML` document, you get an `HTML` file with two `<body>` elements. So, it is an invalid `HTML` file.
Such a file can be badly rendered in a browser (most of browsers try to "understand" it even it is invalid) or can crash it. So, you have to **choose a solution that produce a *valid* `HTML` file**.

I see two options to render a *valid* `HTML` file.

#### Use `knitr` child document

See the documentation about child document [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/#using-chunk-option-child-for-markdown-rmd-documents). I think this is the most adapted solution to your problem.

#### Include external `HTML` file in an `<iframe>` element

You can embed any external `HTML` file in an [`<iframe>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe). Here's a reproducible example.

Assume that you have the following file named `embedded_file.Rmd`

```
---
title: "Embedded file"
output: html_document
---

This is the content of the embedded file.
```

Here's the content of `main.Rmd` file:

````
---
title: "Include external html file"
output: html_document
---

```{r generate-external-report, include=FALSE}
rmarkdown::render('embedded_file.Rmd')
```

External `HTML` file can be included in an `<iframe>` element:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::tags$iframe(title = "My embedded document", src = "embedded_file.html")
```
````

When you render `main.Rmd`, you get an `<iframe>` with your embedded file.  You have to set the width and height of the `<iframe>` to get a good looking `<iframe>`.

Comment: You are completely right on your comment, that it is a bad practice to just use `readLines` within an `asis` code chunk, I updated my answer accordingly. I am wondering if this is still a bad idea though.

Comment: Your edit is right: there's no problem with an html *fragment*. It's important to distinguish html *standalone* and html *fragment*. However, the question was about including html *standalone* file.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work with the <iframe> option! For the knitr option I have an issue and I think it's because my child document also has YAML header to include my external HTML file. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is an ugly hack but just create your `html` file and within your markdown, create a code chunk like this:

````
```{r, results='asis'}
cat(readLines('my_text.html'))
```
````

Don't forget to have an empty line at the end, otherwise you get an ugly warning.

Maybe this is what @Clock Slave was referring to.

**EDIT:**

Since I got a downvote on this, I want to at least comment. As @romles pointed out, an html file is only allowed to have one `body` tag. So with my `readLines` command, you shouldn't read a complete HTML file, but you can for example read paragraphs or tables, etc. This shouldn't be a problem. So a little example could be

```
<h1>My test html file</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
<ul>
  <li>bla</li>
  <li>blubb</li>
</ul>
```