# P-values significance not showed in stargazer html regression table

Tags: r, html-table, rstudio, stargazer

I am having trouble with the Notes significance (asterisks) not appearing when using stargazer to format html tables. The result is ok when using latex.

Here is my source file "teste.Rmd"

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r data}
#some data
set.seed(123)
X = rnorm(500,10,3)
Y = 10+ 3*I(X^1.2) + rnorm(500)
# models
m1 = lm(Y~X)
m2 = lm(Y~X+I(X^2))

```

```{r res,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,results='asis'}
library(stargazer)
stargazer(m1,m2,type = 'html',title = 'Models' )

```
````

The result is below

[image]

The same with latex produces this
[image]

As you can see the asterisks in Notes are formatted correctly with latex but not with html option. How to get the same behavior with html?

Comment: Seems to be a bug, since option `star.char='&#42;'` won't work. You can try `texreg::htmlreg(list(m1, m2), star.symbol = '&#42;')`instead.

Comment: Works!!  Thanks!  Still `stargazer` offers better formatting options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is a bug as @jaySf said in the comments to the original question. But based on @tmfmnk's answer and `htmltools` package I ended with a workaround. This is the updated relevant part of the source file.

````
```{r res,warning=FALSE,message=FALSE,results='hide'}
library(stargazer)
stargazer(m1,m2,type = 'html',title = 'Models', out = "table1.html")
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
htmltools::includeHTML("table1.html")
```
````

Now I got the desired result
[image]

Comment: Now in march 2024 using Quatro with html I have the same problem. This solution is still  valid!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding customized notes using `notes` and `notes.append` parameters as follows:

```
stargazer(m1,m2,type='html',notes="<span>&#42;&#42;&#42;</span>: p<0.01; <span>&#42;&#42;</span>: p<0.05; <span>&#42;</span>: p<0.1",notes.append=F)
```

I originally thought that using backslash to escape `*` will work, e.g. `notes="\\*\\*\\*: p<0.01; \\*\\*: p<0.05; \\*: p<0.1"`. Unfortunately, it doesn't. I also tried to use the HTML code of `*`, i.e. `&#42;`, e.g. `notes="&#42;&#42;&#42;: p<0.01; &#42;&#42;: p<0.05; &#42;: p<0.1"`. Still it doesn't work.

However, surrounding `&#42;` with an HTML tag works. It doesn't have to be `<span></span>`. I tried `<b></b>`, etc. and they worked.

Answer (score 0):

When exported through `out` it is working fine:

```
stargazer(m1,m2,type = 'html',
          title = 'Models',
          out = "/path/table.html")
```

[image]

Comment: That's almost right. As a stand alone table.html works!!! But within the html document the problems persist.

Comment: Maybe try different `style` parameters.